# Handling a redirect after a successful form based payment

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have built a custom payment plug-in to integrate a payment gateway. This integration requires users to complete payment on their hosted webpage and then redirect to a fixed page with payment status parameters.

I plan to handle this by again redirecting users to correct web pages based on the status of their payment or dynamically load the contents of the page using js.

I wanted to know if functions.php would be the correct place to write a code block to handle this flow or a webhook would be a good idea. Thanks in advance.

```
    public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

        global $woocommerce;
        
        $customer_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
                  
        $pStr = "XXX";
        $pStr .= $order_id;   
        $pStr .= $orderDescription;
        $pStr .= (int)($customer_order->order_total * 100);
        $pStr .= '_LANDINGPAGE_';            $pStr .= "transactionType,transactionStatus,transactionId,transactionResultCode,transactionResultMessage,orderNumber";
        $pStr .= intval($seconds.$milliseconds);
        $pStr .= "KEY";    
        
        $hash = hash('md5',$pStr);   
        
        /*
         * Array with parameters for API interaction
         */
        $args = array(
            'orderType' => 'XXX',
            'orderNumber' => $order_id,
            'orderDescription' => $orderDescription,
            'amount' => (int)($customer_order->order_total * 100),
            'redirectUrl' => '_LANDINGPAGE_',
            'redirectUrlParameters' => 'transactionType,transactionStatus,transactionId,transactionResultCode,transactionResultMessage,orderNumber',
            'timestamp' => intval($seconds.$milliseconds),
            'hash' => $hash
        );
        
        // send to gateway
        
         $req_url = add_query_arg(  $args,  "_TESTPAYMENT_GATEWAYURL_");

        return array('result' => 'success','redirect' => $req_url );
    
    }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you do this in your plugin? Makes no sense to me putting this outsite of it.

Comment: I'm redirecting users to the payment gateway in the return statement of process_payment() . I will edit question to include my payment plugin code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by using template_Redirect in function.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout' );

function woocommerce_redirect_after_checkout(){

if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' )  ) {
    return;
}
if( is_checkout() && ( $txnStat == 1 || $txnStat == 5) ) { 
  // Success credit card and eCheck

  $order_key =  $_GET['userChoice1'] ;

//generate a successful order-recieved link
  $url = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/checkout/order-received'.'/'.$order_id.'/'.'?key='. $order_key ;

  $order->add_order_note($note);     
  $order->payment_complete();    
  wp_redirect( $url );
  exit;
    
}
```